# Apache Condition - Different Rewrite Based on Existence of Query String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/33\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^33.php "/api.php" [NC,L]
```

I want to rewrite `/33.php` to `/api.php`, and anything other than that, such as `/33.php?foo=bar` to get a 404. How could I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer George. I notice you're new, and want you to know you now have enough reputation to be able to also upvote answers using the up arrow next to the tick for accepting it. This gives a bit more reputation (+10) to the user who gave the answer, and indicates you approve of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as shown below. The query string is in its own variable.

```
# Rewrite /33.php with no query string to /api.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^33\.php$ /api.php [NC,L]

# Return 404 for /33.php?anything
RewriteRule ^33\.php$ - [NC,R=404,L]
```